# nuget Cannot locate resource 'productupdate/productupdatebar.xaml'

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, f#, asp.net-web-api, nuget

I can't get nuget to run on a Visual Studio F# Web API project template.  It's a vanilla install on Windows 8 and I just downloaded the online template for MVC 4 F# and created a Web API project.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's difficult to debug without knowing more.  At what point are you having problems?  Do you have compile errors?

Comment: No compile errors.   Error when selecting manage nuget from menu

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Applying the latest visual studio update fixed the problem.

Comment: Not for me ! and there are no update coming in sight..... arrggh.. that started when I downloaded a F# WPF template

Comment: reinstalling nuget worked

Comment: I have the same problem since doing the F# ASP.NET MVC4 template.

Comment: Also with F# ASP.NET MVC4, reinstall of nuget solved the problem.